# Python and Flask I can't get to the routes defined in views.py

Tags: python-3.x, flask, routes

I have application in Python and using Flask. This is web api application without html files.
In server_pi.py I have:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello():
   return "Hello world"
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8082, debug=True)
```

Application start and when I type in browser: `localhost:8082/` it shows me `Hello world`
But I have additional endpoints in views.py file that is placed in app folder. This is structer of my project:

```
rpi_server2:
-app:
  -views.py
  -init.py
-server_pi.py
-run.py
```

In `views.py` I have endpoints:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
    def hello():
       return "Hello world"

@app.route("/index2")
    def hello():
       return "Hello world2"
```

And I can't get to this endpoints. When I type `localhost:8082/index2` in the browser I get `404 error`. When I comment `@app.route('/')` in the `server_pi.py` the result is the same.

---

This is code of the sample application that I have on my RPi.
`server_pi.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
#@app.route("/turnleft")
#@app.route("/")
#def hello():
# return "Hello World!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8082, debug=True)
```

in folder app I have file `init.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
 
app = Flask(__name__)
from app import views
```

and the second file in app folder `views.py`:

```
from app import app
 
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

And when I type `localhost:8082/index` in the browser I have `404`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle multiple routes with a single function by simply stacking additional route decorators above any route!
**You cannot have more than one function with the same name**
You can just change the name of the second function to hello2

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def hello():
   return "Hello world"

@app.route("/index2")
def hello2():
   return "Hello world2"
```

Comment: I added code of the simplified application, only three files